# Laptop shows no sign of life: motherboard or power supply issue?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, power-supply, power

My Toshiba Qosmio x505-q890 laptop has suddenly stopped powering on. Symptoms are the laptop simply does not respond to the power button when pressed, but when the DC adapter is connected the adapter LED light on the laptop comes on. Tried holding the power button on whilst DC and battery are disconnected, using another battery I know works, and tested the DC adapter and it's fine.

Opened it up and upon a close inspection of all connectors, including power connectors and the entire motherboard (both sides), I cannot find anything out of the ordinary like popped capacitors, transistors or any other components. Bought a replacement power button board suspecting it was that, no change. Took out my multi meter and found a component level schematic of the laptop here [schematic](ftp://helpedia.com/pub/temp/uploads/ala_borbe/Toshiba/) and using this video [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ox7kZSxKJfk) I was able to trace both battery and adapter power circuits and inspect and check components there.

Without even pressing the power button, with the adapter connected, there is 19V present everywhere it should be according to the schematic. The FETs for the adapter circuit also seem to be fine as does the 3V/5V regulator which is outputting the correct voltages for when the laptop is off.

Now this is where my limited knowledge in electronics comes in and I wouldn't really know how to test further. At this point I am assuming it's not the DC adapter or the battery, but rather the motherboard and I did find a replacement motherboard which I will purchase if all else fails. The only reason I'm doing this is I feel it's a waste to throw the motherboard away until I have at least attempted a repair. I know this can be taken into a repair shop and it might me the next step.

However, my question is does anyone know or have an idea as to what might be the cause of the laptop not powering on and what I could check for? I'm all for learning new things and actually enjoined tracing the motherboard circuit so up for suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once when I left my Toshiba laptop on sleep and it ran out of battery.

I solved the problem by removing battery pressing power button for very long (30 seconds). Then connecting battery and power supply and repeating. It came back to life and still working years on.

Answer (score 0):

Lithcion battery’s hit a safety after so many discharges to prevent dying.  If nothing was spilled I’d assume it’s ur battery..  u can warp in a towel and then put into a freezer ziploc leave overnight and plug it into laptop then plug charger in.  That should make the battery regain charging abilities for a little longer.

```
You can also disconnect battery leave it out.  Unhook cmos battery then reconnect,  then recon t the cable that plugs battery into mother board if it has one,.  A MacBook Pro had this same problem and those battery’s plugged into a little com slot looking plug.  Also disconnect power button from laptop then reconnect to motherboard.  Plug the computer in.  Without battery hooked up.  Then plug in battery and the pc should auto start to post..  or it should when u turn it on via power button without battery.  That is another way to know if it is a battery issue..  Personally the freezer always works in my kids tablets controllers phones about anything they let die over and over.  If the freezer doesn’t do it u need a special charger to jump it.   Or be careful and use ur car battery and just give it a quick touch to the ground and hits then battery will also jump out of safety cutoff.  Begin to charge if it is the battery causing your issues.  Otherwise,.  Leave it plugged in without battery and just don’t turn it off. Always hibernate or sleep.
```

Comment: Can you please edit this answer to fix formatting, spelling, etc, to make it more clear.